# Static html to wordpress JS plugin issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am transforming my static html to a wordpress theme. Everything is going fine expect one little thingy.

My static html uses this script in the head

```
<script>
  // terrificjs bootstrap
  (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
          var $page = $('body');
          var config = {
            dependencyPath: {
              plugin: 'javascripts/'
            }
          }
          var application = new Tc.Application($page, config);
          application.registerModules();
          application.start();
      });
  })(Tc.$);
</script>
```

I'm not sure what it does. I keep getting this error in my console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tc is not defined
```

I've tried something like this with url at the plugin: line

```
plugin: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/javascripts/'
```

But the error keeps occuring
Anyone knows what this script is for and how to implement it in my wordpress theme?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looks to be this: http://terrifically.org/api/application/

Comment: Yeah, I figured this out. Thanks anyways :) I still don't know why it gives me this error :/

Comment: If _"Tc is not defined"_, you haven't included the TerrificJS library in your project

Comment: It is included in an other .js file and the file is being loaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue!
The TerrificJS Library was being loaded after the function.